# What does V= in an interface for TS mean?

Tags: typescript

What's the difference between

```
interface FieldAProps<V = FieldTypes['A']>
  extends GeneralFieldProps<V> {}
```

vs.

```
interface FieldAProps<FieldTypes['A']>
  extends GeneralFieldProps<V> {}
```

Comment: Is your lower code what you really have? V is never defined there

Comment: Yeah I don't know what V is, it's never been defined

Comment: Then your second code won't work at all. You can't use things without defining them, so this boils down to an optional type parameter vs a syntax error.

Comment: Got it so it's an optional type